# Hp Laserjet Mfp 436 printer installation issue in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hplip

I have a printer Hp Laserjet Mfp 436 nda, I am unable to install the printer drivers in hplip-gui ubuntu 16.04, 14.04 & 12.04 because the mfp 436 model is not available while installing the drivers. I need help how to install the drivers.